# Concatenating the strings of 2 arrays into 1 array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, string, concatenation

I read (in the documentation) how to concatenate the strings of one array with another string:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a.collect! {|x| x + "!" }
a                          #=>  [ "a!", "b!", "c!", "d!" ]
```

but what I haven't figured out is how to concatenate the strings of 2 arrays into one.  For example:

```
field_suffix = %w[prev curr]
field_names = %w[_first_name _last_name]
```

What I'd like to see is this:

```
["prev_first_name", "curr_first_name", "prev_last_name", "curr_last_name"]
```

The order doesn't matter. It could be:

```
["prev_first_name", "prev_last_name", "curr_first_name", "curr_last_name"]
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers - they all work great.  I accepted JavaNut13's answer because it was first but I actually went back and used megas answer because it seemed the 'sexiest'.  I voted all the answers up because they all work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with the following:

```
out=[]
pre=["sub", "pre"]
suf=["less", "ness"]
pre.each do |p|
  suf.each do |s|
    out.push(p+s)
  end
end
puts out
```

Or in less lines:

```
out=[]
pre=["sub", "pre"]
suf=["less", "ness"]
pre.each{|p| suf.each{|s| out.push(p+s)}}
```

This will not **return** the array (sadly), you have to have the second array; `out` which will be subless, subness, preless, preness

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, this gives me out = ["sub","pre"]

Comment: See answer, print `out` array

Answer (score 3):

```
field_suffix.product(field_names).map(&:join)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
field_suffix = %w[prev curr]
field_names = %w[_first_name _last_name]

result = field_suffix.product(field_names).collect {|suffix, name| suffix + name}
```

See [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product) for details